# What do I use for 'Me' in a Public Shared Sub (vb)?

Tags: vb.net

I am using a third party product where the calls look like this:

```
    Logging.Log.ErrorMessage(Me, "Error while Processing: " & ex.Message)
```

Unfortunately, this will not compile in a proecdure defined as:

```
    Public Shared Sub MainLoop(ByVal onsiteProfiles As IEnumerable(Of OnsiteIfcProfile))
```

The error says: 'Me' is only valid within an instance method. How do I correctly specify the Object required here?

Comment: `Me` refers to the current instance, in a `Shared` context there is no instance. That's the reason for the compiler error.  You haven't mentioned the signature of the method `Logging.Log.ErrorMessage`, what type does it expect? Maybe you could simply pass `Nothing`.

Comment: The method Logging.Log.ErrorMessage expects an Object as First Parameter. Where I can use me, I see meaningful messages, i.e. OnSiteIFCClass.ServiceClass.OnStart. Where I have used My.Application, I get rubbish - i.e. My.MyApplication

Comment: What is the purpose of the first parameter? Have you tried to pass `Nothing` as suggested above? [`My.Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163972.aspx#S3) is something different than `Me` since it refers to the application.

Comment: I have tried passing Nothing, but I want the information.

Comment: What kind of information? If you want to log the current call stack you could use `New System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true).ToString()` in the method (if you can change the method).

Comment: What do I use for 'Me' in a Public Shared Sub? The method clearly requires an object, similar to that referenced by the Me keyword. Is there an equivalent for the Shared procedures or not?

Comment: There is no `Me` in a shared/static context as mentioned above. `Me`(`this` in C#, java) refers to the current class' instance. You are in a `Shared` method which means by definition that there is no instance. So either don't make it `Shared` or pass a different object. But since it's not clear what the method really does with this parameter or what kind of `Objct`s are allowed at all, it's impossible to provide an alternative. You haven't even mentioned what kind of application this is. Maybe `ErrorMessage` has another overload that accepts a different parameter.

Comment: I wonder how the method can determine the calling method from the class which can contain multiple methods. By passing an instance of the current class i can inspect it's current state in the logger. But i cannot detect the name of the method itself. Therefore you need the `StackTrace` as shown above. Of course you could pass `New ClassName` but that seems to be pretty pointless, all the more if the constructor of the current class is expensive or has side-effects. Maybe it just inspects the type of `Me`, you can pass that by `GetType(ClassName)`. But note that this is not an instance of it.

Comment: The Logging software gets the name of the process from the Me keyword. i.e OnSiteIFC.ServiceClass.OnStart. This is very useful for debugging. If I use Nothing, I get an error message - instance argument is null. If I use My.Application, the logging software displays My.MyApplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't have any object instance in shared subs, you could pass `Nothing` as the first parameter if that is allowed.

Maybe it would be a good idea to pass `My.Application` as the first parameter to signal that the log entry comes from the application main loop.